# full text search on multiple columns with Coredata on ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, full-text-search

i use core data in my app. i have 4 columns(id,name,description,specs).
 I want to full text search across all these columns.
 Is it possible with core data?
If anybody can provide me reference to tutorial or code snippets.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. [iTunes Style Search](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/11/25/adding-itunes-style-search-to-your-core-data-application/)